# Why does lerna run "prepublish" when bootstrapping?

Tags: lerna

When I run `lerna bootstrap`, according to the docs:

```
Usage

$ lerna bootstrap
Bootstrap the packages in the current Lerna repo. Installs all of their dependencies and links any cross-dependencies.

When run, this command will:

npm install all external dependencies of each package.
Symlink together all Lerna packages that are dependencies of each other.
npm run prepublish in all bootstrapped packages (unless --ignore-prepublish is passed).
npm run prepare in all bootstrapped packages.
```

Since bootstrapping has nothing to do with publishing, why does it run `prepublish`? Why is it the default?

Answer (score 8):

Because `npm install` also triggers the `prepublish` script. If you want your prepublish scripts not to be triggered use the `prepublishOnly` script instead. 
You can read all about this in the [NPM script documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)